# Erro na realizar criteria com filtro em objeto que pertence a composite ID

Tags: java, hibernate, groovy, grails

Acontece um erro quando tento fazer uma busca na classe de domínio Carro aplicando um filtro na Marca que é uma FK e faz parte do composite ID.

```
class Carro implements Serializable {

    Marca marca
    LocalDate dataFabricacao

    static constraints = {
        marca nullable: false
        dataFabricacao nullable: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        table "carro"
        dynamicUpdate true

        id composite: ["marca", "dataFabricacao"], generator: "assigned"
        marca column: "cod_marca"

        version false
    }

}


class Marca {

    Long id
    
    static mapping = {
        table 'marca'
        dynamicUpdate true

        id column: "cod_marca", generator: "sequence", params: [sequence: 'seq_cod_marca']

        version false
    }

    static constraints = {
        id maxSize: 6
    }   
    
}


List<Carro> carroList = Carro.createCriteria().list {
    marca {
        idEq(18L)
    }

    fetchMode('marca', FetchMode.JOIN)
}
```

Acontece o seguinte erro no terminal: **Error | 2021-01-29 10:46:27,763 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter - ORA-00904: "MARCA1_"."COD_MARCA": identificador inválido**

O SQL que é executado é esse aqui:

```
select
    this_.cod_marca as cod1_22_0_,
    this_.data_fabricacao as data2_22_0_
from
    carros this_ 
where
     (
         marca1_.cod_marca=?
     )
```

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de aplicar esse filtro ou se não é possível com o objeto marca pertencendo ao composite ID

Hibernate versão: 3.6.10.19

Grails versão: 2.5.6

Java versão: 1.8.0_281